# jQuery: Store input value to array

Tags: jquery, html, arrays

I'd like to store some data from inputs and store them to an array.

Example:

```
input 1: [some text]
input 2: [more text]
input 3: [some more]
```

As I click save, the values in these 3 inputs should be saved to an array so that later on I can print them like this:

```
Array[1] has: some text, more text, some more
Array[2] has: name1, name2, name3
```

This is what I have so far: http://jsfiddle.net/P7QXa/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map()` like this

```
var arr = $('input:text').map(function(){
             return this.value;
          }).get();
```

Demo `--->`  http://jsfiddle.net/P7QXa/1/

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick, modified a little to get the expected output: http://jsfiddle.net/P7QXa/3/